# Swift adding custom keyboard or numpad in app

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

What types of restrictions is there when adding a custom keyboard or numpad in an app?

I know that some apps requires you to enable keyboards in your system settings.

I recently saw an app using this keyboard:

[image]

The app does not require you to activate the keyboard. So how can I make my own custom numpad like this one?

Feel free to share any tutorials/libraries

thanks,

Comment: [A Swift example of Custom Views for Data Input (custom in-app keyboard)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474771/a-swift-example-of-custom-views-for-data-input-custom-in-app-keyboard)

Answer (score 1):

There's a great swift keyboard/calculator tutorial out there that will serve as a starting point for what you're doing:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-creating-a-custom-keyboard-in-swift--cms-22344

In terms of "restrictions", you can add the keyboard to the parent app without any problems. If you want to make your keyboard available in OTHER apps, then you will need to adhere to the restrictions that Apple lays out on this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html  - search for "trust"

Swift and Xcode are both moving targets that are updated more often than a project can be completed! So be ready to deal with constant updates as you go through the learning curve. Sometimes the time it takes for a client to approve something is enough time for the Swift/xCode/iOS paradigm to change enough to require you to "fix" things that already worked before submitting for approval. Just row row gently down the stream.