# A Swift example of Custom Views for Data Input (custom in-app keyboard)

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, custom-keyboard

## Goal

I want to make a custom keyboard that is only used within my app, not a system keyboard that needs to be installed.

## What I have read and tried

**Documentation**

- [App Extension Programming Guide: Custom Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html)
- [Custom Views for Data Input](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html)

The first article above states:

> Make sure a custom, systemwide keyboard is indeed what you want to
> develop. To provide a fully custom keyboard for just your app or to
> supplement the system keyboard with custom keys in just your app, the
> iOS SDK provides other, better options. Read about custom input views
> and input accessory views in Custom Views for Data Input in Text
> Programming Guide for iOS.

That is what led me to the second article above. However, that article did not have enough detail to get me started.

**Tutorials**

- [iOS 8: Creating a Custom Keyboard in Swift](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-creating-a-custom-keyboard-in-swift--cms-22344)
- [How to make a custom keyboard in iOS 8 using Swift](https://www.weheartswift.com/make-custom-keyboard-ios-8-using-swift/)
- [Xcode 6 Tutorial: iOS 8.0 Simple Custom Keyboard in Swift](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W_Q91TY1J-o)
- [Creating a Custom Keyboard Using iOS 8 App Extension](http://www.appcoda.com/custom-keyboard-tutorial/)

I was able to get a working keyboard from the second tutorial in the list above. However, I couldn't find any tutorials that showed how to make an in app only keyboard as described in the [Custom Views for Data Input](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html) documentation.

**Stack Overflow**

I also asked (and answered) these questions on my way to answering the current question.

- [How to input text using the buttons of an in-app custom keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33497693/how-to-input-text-using-the-buttons-of-an-in-app-custom-keyboard)
- [Delegates in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33549729/3681880)

## Question

Does anyone have a minimal example (with even one button) of an in app custom keyboard? I am not looking for a whole tutorial, just a proof of concept that I can expand on myself.

Comment: In how many places do you have to enter input with this keyboard? If it's just one and there isn't much stuff in the view, you could just make the keyboard part of the view.

Comment: Eventually I would like to make a keyboard with 20 or 30 buttons. First, though, I would like to make a very simple keyboard with just a button or two to learn the process.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The key is to use the existing [`UIKeyInput`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyinput) protocol, to which `UITextField` already conforms. Then your keyboard view need only to send [`insertText()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyinput/1614543-inserttext) and [`deleteBackward()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyinput/1614572-deletebackward) to the control.

The following example creates a custom numeric keyboard:

```swift
class DigitButton: UIButton {
    var digit: Int = 0
}

class NumericKeyboard: UIView {
    weak var target: (UIKeyInput & UITextInput)?
    var useDecimalSeparator: Bool

    var numericButtons: [DigitButton] = (0...9).map {
        let button = DigitButton(type: .system)
        button.digit = $0
        button.setTitle("\($0)", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        button.accessibilityTraits = [.keyboardKey]
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapDigitButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }

    var deleteButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("⌫", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        button.accessibilityTraits = [.keyboardKey]
        button.accessibilityLabel = "Delete"
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapDeleteButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    lazy var decimalButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        let decimalSeparator = Locale.current.decimalSeparator ?? "."
        button.setTitle(decimalSeparator, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        button.accessibilityTraits = [.keyboardKey]
        button.accessibilityLabel = decimalSeparator
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapDecimalButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    init(target: UIKeyInput & UITextInput, useDecimalSeparator: Bool = false) {
        self.target = target
        self.useDecimalSeparator = useDecimalSeparator
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

// MARK: - Actions

extension NumericKeyboard {
    @objc func didTapDigitButton(_ sender: DigitButton) {
        insertText("\(sender.digit)")
    }

    @objc func didTapDecimalButton(_ sender: DigitButton) {
        insertText(Locale.current.decimalSeparator ?? ".")
    }

    @objc func didTapDeleteButton(_ sender: DigitButton) {
        target?.deleteBackward()
    }
}

// MARK: - Private initial configuration methods

private extension NumericKeyboard {
    func configure() {
        autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        addButtons()
    }

    func addButtons() {
        let stackView = createStackView(axis: .vertical)
        stackView.frame = bounds
        stackView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(stackView)

        for row in 0 ..< 3 {
            let subStackView = createStackView(axis: .horizontal)
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(subStackView)

            for column in 0 ..< 3 {
                subStackView.addArrangedSubview(numericButtons[row * 3 + column + 1])
            }
        }

        let subStackView = createStackView(axis: .horizontal)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(subStackView)

        if useDecimalSeparator {
            subStackView.addArrangedSubview(decimalButton)
        } else {
            let blank = UIView()
            blank.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
            blank.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
            subStackView.addArrangedSubview(blank)
        }

        subStackView.addArrangedSubview(numericButtons[0])
        subStackView.addArrangedSubview(deleteButton)
    }

    func createStackView(axis: NSLayoutConstraint.Axis) -> UIStackView {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = axis
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        return stackView
    }

    func insertText(_ string: String) {
        guard let range = target?.selectedRange else { return }

        if let textField = target as? UITextField, textField.delegate?.textField?(textField, shouldChangeCharactersIn: range, replacementString: string) == false {
            return
        }

        if let textView = target as? UITextView, textView.delegate?.textView?(textView, shouldChangeTextIn: range, replacementText: string) == false {
            return
        }

        target?.insertText(string)
    }
}

// MARK: - UITextInput extension

extension UITextInput {
    var selectedRange: NSRange? {
        guard let textRange = selectedTextRange else { return nil }

        let location = offset(from: beginningOfDocument, to: textRange.start)
        let length = offset(from: textRange.start, to: textRange.end)
        return NSRange(location: location, length: length)
    }
}
```

Then you can:

```
textField.inputView = NumericKeyboard(target: textField)
```

That yields:

[image]

Or, if you want a decimal separator, too, you can:

```
textField.inputView = NumericKeyboard(target: textField, useDecimalSeparator: true)
```

The above is fairly primitive, but it illustrates the idea: Make you own input view and use the `UIKeyInput` protocol to communicate keyboard input to the control.

Also please note the use of `accessibilityTraits` to get the correct “Spoken Content” » “Speak Screen” behavior. And if you use images for your buttons, make sure to set `accessibilityLabel`, too.

Comment: I'm accepting this not because I've tried it yet, but because you look like you know what you are doing more than I do. Thanks for the answer. I'm planning to do more IME work in the future so I'll add a comment or ping you with a question if I run into any problems.

Comment: I would like to add Done button in this keyboard, i add that but now on action how to resign keyboard

Comment: @RahulPhate - Change `target` from a `UIKeyInput?` to a `(UIResponder & UIKeyInput)?` (and make the corresponding change to the `init` method, too). Then you can call `target?.resignFirstResponder()` in your button handler.

Comment: Thank-you Rob. The code works beautifully. I made a hexadecimal version of your code. https://github.com/PepperoniJoe/HexadecimalKeyboard

Comment: @Rob - this is great!  I would like to place the keyboard in specific place on the screen, preferably inside a UIView.  How would I go about doing that?

Comment: The idea of `inputView` is to use your own custom keyboard/view in place of the standard keyboard. But if you don’t want it presented where a keyboard normally is, then perhaps you don’t want to use `inputView` at all, but rather just a bunch of buttons placed in some view that update some label as you tap on them. If you have additional questions, though, I’d suggest that comments here under this answer might not be the right place for this discussion. If you don’t find anything after doing some research, just post your own question...

Comment: @Rob - I'd like to be able to show the keyboard on just half of the screen when the phone is rotated into Landscape mode.  Is that possible using ````inputView````?

Comment: how to use this with swiftui?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the solution, I've been looking for a solution. but don't you think we need to that "  let button = DigitButton(type: .system)" because here every time we create the button which stays forever in the memory. so whenever I visit a screen digitButtons accumulate (even if I exit a screen and go back for it the number doubles). 
Is it a kind of memory leak or what? and do you have any best solution for it ? or if I am missing something and I am wrong please tell me. Thank you

Comment: @Elin If you don't instantiate buttons, you won't have anything to tap on. Lol. If you are leaking these buttons, it is likely because you are leaking the `UITextField` or `UITextView` for which you have set this `inputView`. That can happen if you are leaking your view controller, for whose view/storyboard/nib is being used. But the problem is not in the instantiation of the buttons, undoubtedly something higher up in the view and/or view controller hierarchy. But I just tested this, and buttons are instantiated and released fine. In short, your problem rests elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, it was really helpful you put me on the right path:)  but is a new keyboard created every time i have a new textfield ? So if I have 5 textfields, so i have 5 keyboards which means 100 digitButtons in the memory. Right?

Comment: Yeah, you want a different keyboard instance for every control (so that each can communicate to its respective `UITextField`). So, yes, that means that if you have twelve buttons on each keyboard, and five text fields, then yes, you are instantiating 60 buttons. 12

Answer (score 81):

[image]

This is a basic in-app keyboard. The same method could be used to make just about any keyboard layout. Here are the main things that need to be done:

- Create the keyboard layout in an .xib file, whose owner is a .swift file that contains a `UIView` subclass.
- Tell the `UITextField` to use the custom keyboard.
- Use a delegate to communicate between the keyboard and the main view controller.

## Create the .xib keyboard layout file

- In Xcode go to **File > New > File... > iOS > User Interface > View** to create the .xib file.
- I called mine Keyboard.xib
- Add the buttons that you need.
- Use auto layout constraints so that no matter what size the keyboard is, the buttons will resize accordingly.
- Set the File's Owner (not the root view) to be the Keyboard.swift file. This is a common source of error. See the note at the end.

## Create the .swift UIView subclass keyboard file

- In Xcode go to **File > New > File... > iOS > Source > Cocoa Touch Class** to create the .swift file.
- I called mine Keyboard.swift
- Add the following code:

  ```
  import UIKit

  // The view controller will adopt this protocol (delegate)
  // and thus must contain the keyWasTapped method
  protocol KeyboardDelegate: class {
      func keyWasTapped(character: String)
  }

  class Keyboard: UIView {

      // This variable will be set as the view controller so that 
      // the keyboard can send messages to the view controller.
      weak var delegate: KeyboardDelegate?

      // MARK:- keyboard initialization

      required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
          super.init(coder: aDecoder)
          initializeSubviews()
      }

      override init(frame: CGRect) {
          super.init(frame: frame)
          initializeSubviews()
      }

      func initializeSubviews() {
          let xibFileName = "Keyboard" // xib extention not included
          let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(xibFileName, owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! UIView
          self.addSubview(view)
          view.frame = self.bounds
      }

      // MARK:- Button actions from .xib file

      @IBAction func keyTapped(sender: UIButton) {
          // When a button is tapped, send that information to the 
          // delegate (ie, the view controller)
          self.delegate?.keyWasTapped(character: sender.titleLabel!.text!) // could alternatively send a tag value
      }

  }
  ```
- Control drag from the buttons in the .xib file to the `@IBAction` method in the .swift file to hook them all up.
- Note that the protocol and delegate code. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33549729/3681880) for a simple explanation about how delegates work.

## Set up the View Controller

- Add a `UITextField` to your main storyboard and connect it to your view controller with an `IBOutlet`. Call it `textField`.
- Use the following code for the View Controller:

  ```
  import UIKit

  class ViewController: UIViewController, KeyboardDelegate {

      @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          // initialize custom keyboard
          let keyboardView = Keyboard(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 300))
          keyboardView.delegate = self // the view controller will be notified by the keyboard whenever a key is tapped

          // replace system keyboard with custom keyboard
          textField.inputView = keyboardView
      }

      // required method for keyboard delegate protocol
      func keyWasTapped(character: String) {
          textField.insertText(character)
      }
  }
  ```
- Note that the view controller adopts the `KeyboardDelegate` protocol that we defined above.

## Common error

If you are getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, it is probably because you set the view's custom class as Keyboard.swift rather than do this for the nib File's Owner.

Select Keyboard.nib and then choose File's Owner.

[image]

Make sure that the custom class for the root view is blank.

[image]

Comment: When I click keys not call `keyWasTapped` method. any idea?

Comment: @Piraba, Is `@IBAction func keyTapped` called? If no, then you probably didn't hook up the IBActions. If yes, then you probably didn't set up the delegate correctly.

Comment: `keyTapped` called. Not passed to `keyWasTapped` delegate method

Comment: Do you know, how to control custom keyboard withing our application if we use the app extension keyboard

Comment: @Piraba, This sounds like a bigger question than can be answered in the comments. I don't have experience with this. If you can't find the answer elsewhere try asking a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Feel free to link back to it from here.

Comment: @Surangch This is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634740/swift-custom-system-keyboard-within-my-app-only

Comment: I am unable to drag from UIButton to keyTapped function.

I try creating my own function but nothing happens when I press the button.

File owner is set to the Keyboard Swift file. The key difference is that I'm doing all of this in an actual custom keyboard extension.

Anyone got any hints?

Comment: @Suragch, I had an issue with let keyboardView = Keyboard(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 300)).  I do not know if a recent update to Swift caused it.  With the "width" initially set to 0, the buttons did not respond to touch up inside.  Even though the view automatically resized to the full width and was visible.  I changed the call to be the minimum size of the frame in XIB to include the buttons and everything worked perfectly.  Thanks for the post!  This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @McInvale, thanks for the note. I'll add this question to my list of things to update.

Comment: The delegate method is not called correctly, you are missing `character:`

Comment: @Daniel, I haven't looked at this for a while. I'm not really sure what you are talking about. Calling `self.delegate?.keyWasTapped(sender.titleLabel!.text!)` sends "character" (which is a `String`, probably poor naming), doesn't it?

Comment: @Daniel, Ah, now I understand. Updated Swift syntax. Thanks for editing it in.

Comment: Hi,
I was wondering how can I set this custom keyboard for all of my textField's inputViews?

Comment: @KeyhanKamangar, I haven't worked on this for a while, but I think if you have multiple text fields then you can check which one has focus and set it to the correct one in `keyWasTapped`.

Comment: @Suragch, Well I achieved it by creating a subclass of UITextField and set it's inputView to my custom input view but unfortunately I have problem with textField.insertText() function. It seems that by using this function for inserting text into text field, the delegate function (shouldChangeCharactersIn) does not get called.

Comment: Height should be always 300 or does not matter ?

Comment: @MaksimKniazev No, you don't need to use 300 for the height.

Comment: @Piraba how do you connect buttons with action

Comment: Here are some tutorials:

https://riptutorial.com/ios/example/16976/create-a-custom-in-app-keyboard (the same in the answer)

https://digitalleaves.com/blog/2016/12/custom-in-app-keyboards/

Comment: FWIW, I’d suggest using the existing `UIKeyInput` protocol, rather than defining your own.

Comment: @Suragch - I've got everything wired up and running, but I have a couple of noob questions:  what do I put in the ````@IBAction```` that I hooked up to the buttons?  (Can you I've me one example?)  Should ````@IBAction func keyTapped```` be hooked to anything? I don't see that function getting called at all.

Comment: @Greg, I haven't worked on iOS IMEs for a while but you can study the source code of this one that I did a while back: https://github.com/suragch/MongolianIPAKeyboardContainer That one is a system keyboard, though. This one includes an in app keyboard: https://github.com/suragch/Chimee-iOS

Answer (score 12):

Building on Suragch's answer, I needed a done and backspace button and if you're a noob like me heres some errors you might encounter and the way I solved them.

**Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors?**
I included:

```
@objc(classname)
class classname: UIView{ 
}
```

fixed my issue however Suragch's updated answer seems to solve this the more appropriate/correct way.

**Getting SIGABRT Error?**
Another silly thing was dragging the connections the wrong way, causing SIGABRT error. Do not drag from the function to the button but instead the button to the function.

**Adding a Done Button**
I added this to the protocol in keyboard.swift:

```
protocol KeyboardDelegate: class {
    func keyWasTapped(character: String)
    func keyDone()
}
```

Then connected a new IBAction from my done button to keyboard.swift like so:

```
@IBAction func Done(sender: UIButton) {
    self.delegate?.keyDone()
}
```

and then jumped back to my viewController.swift where i am using this keyboard and added this following after the function keyWasTapped:

```
func keyDone() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

**Adding Backspace**
This tripped me up a lot, because you must set the textField.delegate to self in the viewDidLoad() method (shown later).

*First:* In keyboard.swift add to the protocol func backspace():

```
protocol KeyboardDelegate: class {
    func keyWasTapped(character: String)
    func keyDone()
    func backspace()
}
```

*Second:* Connect a new IBAction similar to the Done action:

```
@IBAction func backspace(sender: UIButton) {
    self.delegate?.backspace()
}
```

*Third:* Over to the viewController.swift where the NumberPad is appearing.

*Important:* In viewDidLoad() set all textFields that will be using this keyboard. So your viewDidLoad() should look something like this:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.myTextField1.delegate = self
    self.myTextField2.delegate = self

    // initialize custom keyboard
    let keyboardView = keyboard(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 240))
    keyboardView.delegate = self // the view controller will be notified by the keyboard whenever a key is tapped

    // replace system keyboard with custom keyboard
    myTextField1.inputView = keyboardView
    myTextField2.inputView = keyboardView
}
```

I'm not sure how to, if there is a way to just do this to all textFields that are in the view. This would be handy...

*Forth:* Still in viewController.swift we need to add a variable and two functions. It will look like this:

```
var activeTextField = UITextField()

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    print("Setting Active Textfield")
    self.activeTextField = textField
    print("Active textField Set!")
}

func backspace() {
    print("backspaced!")
    activeTextField.deleteBackward()
}
```

*Explanation of whats happening here:*

1. You make a variable that will hold a textField.
2. When the "textFieldDidBeginEditing" is called it sets the variable so it knows which textField we are dealing with. I've added a lot of prints() so we know everything is being executed.
3. Our backspace function then checks the textField we are dealing with and uses .deleteBackward(). This removes the immediate character before the cursor.

And you should be in business.
Many thanks to Suragchs for helping me get this happening.

Comment: Use `textField.deleteBackward()` to backspace. If you are interested, here is a [demo view controller](https://github.com/suragch/MongolAppDevelopment-iOS/blob/master/Mongol%20App%20Componants/KeyboardDemoVC.swift) and [this](https://github.com/suragch/MongolAppDevelopment-iOS/blob/master/Mongol%20App%20Componants/EnglishKeyboard.swift) is one of the keyboards that I use in it. It shows where I have come since first starting with the example here. I ended up abandoning nibs (for an unrelated reason) and just laying things out programmatically, though I don't necessary recommend that for you.

Comment: if have two textfields.. so need a keyboard custom in first textfield and second textfield can keyboard default by iphone ?.. i wanna hide keyboard default and them show keyboard default

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question marlonpya. If you want the default keyboard for one `textfield` then you do not need to address it in the `viewDidLoad()`. And then if you do want the custom keyboard for the other `textfield` then in `viewDidLoad()` you must set the `textfield` delegate to self and replace the keyboard with the custom keyboard as outlined in the third step above.