# Swift - Custom System Keyboard Within my app only

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I have created custom keyboard and custom system keyboard.Both are working But I need to implement `UIPageControl` in my custom keyboard part. If I choose the custom keyboard.(Using UIView) it is very hard to implement.

I need a solution for following areas.

**My first issue is :**

Custom keyboard is working with the app only. Once I install, if I exit my app , go other app developed my Custom system keyboard will show. Is there any way to configure within my app only.

I found some ideas from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474771/a-swift-example-of-custom-views-for-data-input-custom-in-app-keyboard/33692231?noredirect=1#comment66572866_33692231). Please suggest any idea.

**The second issue is:**

I have to implement the pagination [image: like this]
Without pagination, it is working.

It would be helpful if you provide any help.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the keyboard to be app only you should be creating a custom keyboard via UIView only.

With regards to pagination in a UIView, couldn't you simply put a UIScrollView into the UIView and recreate horizontal pagination?

Comment: Can you add some additional detail?

Comment: Which part would you like additional detail? The custom keyboard or the horizontal pagination?