# iOS: Disable keyboard when begin editing TextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios

How can I disable the keyboard when I touch-up inside a `UITextField`?

What I want to do is show a custom digital keyboard instead of the default one.

Comment: Why don't you just change the keyboard type?

Comment: You can just set the `userInteractionEnabled` as **NO** and place an `UIButton` on your `textField` and show your digital keyboard in the action method of the **Button**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly that you are looking to create a custom keyboard in the app, I don't think we need to disable the default keyboard when we touch-up inside a `UITextField`.

We just need to create a custom view and assign it to the `inputView` property of the `UITextField` to replace the default keyboard.

For example, something like this:

```
yourTextField.inputView = yourCustomKeyboardView
```

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474771/a-swift-example-of-custom-views-for-data-input-custom-in-app-keyboard?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: For Objective-C (Xcode)

In your `viewDidLoad:` set delegate for textfields which you want to disable.

```
self.textfield.delegate = self;
```

and insert this delegate function:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
     if (textField == yourTextfiledOutletInstance) {
         [self showCustomkeyboard];
        return NO;
     }
   return YES;
}

//Show custom keyboard
-(void)showCustomkeyboard{
  // Handle your operation here to show custom keyboard
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set the UITextField delegate in the ViewController class, and then add this method in the class

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
      [textField resignFirstResponder];
      return NO;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `resignFirstResponder` to dismiss your keyboard.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
      [textField resignFirstResponder];
      return NO;
}
```

set `inputView` on the `UITextView` to the custom view you want to be used in place of the system keyboard.

```
myTextView.inputView = myCustomView;
```