# How to make UIKeyboardType for hex input only?

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboardtype

Is there any option in swift to make new UIKeyboardType with only HEX(0-9,A,B,C,D,E,F) value using extension or any other way ? I want keyboard that has only hex character enable on it, user can see clearly that he can only enter hex character, or only hex character is visible on keyboard

Comment: just make your own UIVIew containing buttons for entering HEX Code , and pass it to inputView Property Of UITextField.

Comment: That's nice I'll try this

Comment: @VarunNaharia, late but I posted an example using inputView in case it would help save others time.

Answer (score 4):

This following code creates a hexadecimal keyboard and passes it to inputView, as suggested by Saurabh Prajapati.

The keyboard is designed like this:

[image]

*The design was based on a layout by David Mulder*
https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/58605/128044

The class HexadecimalKeyboard creates the keyboard.

```
protocol RemoveKeyboardDelegate: class {
    func removeKeyboard()
}

class HexButton: UIButton {
    var hexCharacter: String = ""
}

class HexadecimalKeyboard: UIView {
    weak var target   : UIKeyInput?
    weak var delegate : RemoveKeyboardDelegate?
    
    var hexadecimalButtons: [HexButton] = ["0","7","8","9","4","5","6","1","2","3","A","B","C","D","E","F"].map {
        let button = HexButton(type: .system)
        button.hexCharacter = $0
        button.setTitle("\($0)", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.secondarySystemGroupedBackground
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapHexButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }
    
    var deleteButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("⌫", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGray4
        button.accessibilityLabel = "Delete"
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapDeleteButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    var okButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("OK", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGray4
        button.accessibilityLabel = "OK"
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapOKButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    var mainStack: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.spacing      = 10
        stackView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        stackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        stackView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        return stackView
    }()
    
    init(target: UIKeyInput) {
        self.target = target
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        configure()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}


// MARK: - Actions

extension HexadecimalKeyboard {
    @objc func didTapHexButton(_ sender: HexButton) {
        target?.insertText("\(sender.hexCharacter)")
    }
    
    @objc func didTapDeleteButton(_ sender: HexButton) {
        target?.deleteBackward()
    }
    
    @objc func didTapOKButton(_ sender: HexButton) {
        delegate?.removeKeyboard()
    }
}


// MARK: - Private initial configuration methods

private extension HexadecimalKeyboard {
    func configure() {
        self.backgroundColor = .systemGroupedBackground
        autoresizingMask     = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        buildKeyboard()
    }
    
    func buildKeyboard() {
        //MARK: - Add main stackview to keyboard
        mainStack.frame = bounds
        addSubview(mainStack)
        
        //MARK: - Create stackviews
        let panel1         = createStackView(axis: .vertical)
        let panel2         = createStackView(axis: .vertical)
        let panel2Group    = createStackView(axis: .vertical)
        let panel2Controls = createStackView(axis: .horizontal, distribution : .fillProportionally)
 
        
        //MARK: - Create multiple stackviews for numbers
        for row in 0 ..< 3 {
            let panel1Numbers = createStackView(axis: .horizontal)
            panel1.addArrangedSubview(panel1Numbers)
            
            for column in 0 ..< 3 {
                panel1Numbers.addArrangedSubview(hexadecimalButtons[row * 3 + column + 1])
            }
        }
        
        //MARK: - Create multiple stackviews for letters
        for row in 0 ..< 2 {
            let panel2Letters = createStackView(axis: .horizontal)
            panel2Group.addArrangedSubview(panel2Letters)
            
            for column in 0 ..< 3 {
                panel2Letters.addArrangedSubview(hexadecimalButtons[9 + row * 3 + column + 1])
            }
        }
        
        //MARK: - Nest stackviews
        mainStack.addArrangedSubview(panel1)
        panel1.addArrangedSubview(hexadecimalButtons[0])
        mainStack.addArrangedSubview(panel2)
        panel2.addArrangedSubview(panel2Group)
        panel2.addArrangedSubview(panel2Controls)
        panel2Controls.addArrangedSubview(deleteButton)
        panel2Controls.addArrangedSubview(okButton)
        
        //MARK: - Constraint - sets okButton width to two times the width of the deleteButton plus 10 points for the space
        panel2Controls.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
                                        item       : okButton,
                                        attribute  : .width,
                                        relatedBy  : .equal,
                                        toItem     : deleteButton,
                                        attribute  : .width,
                                        multiplier : 2,
                                        constant   : 10))
    }
    
    func createStackView(axis: NSLayoutConstraint.Axis, distribution: UIStackView.Distribution = .fillEqually) -> UIStackView {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis         = axis
        stackView.distribution = distribution
        stackView.spacing      = 10
        return stackView
    }
}
```

*The code was derived from the decimal keyboard example provided by Rob* https://stackoverflow.com/a/57275689/1816667

Then following is an example of how to use the keyboard. In the example, two textfields are set up with the hexadecimal keyboard:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var hexField: [UITextField]!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        hexField[0].inputView  = HexadecimalKeyboard(target: hexField[0])
        hexField[1].inputView  = HexadecimalKeyboard(target: hexField[1])
    }
    
    @IBAction func clickTextField(_ sender: UITextField) {
        sender.reloadInputViews()
        sender.inputView  = HexadecimalKeyboard(target: sender)
        
        let hexadecimalKeyboard  = HexadecimalKeyboard(target: sender)
                sender.inputView = hexadecimalKeyboard
                hexadecimalKeyboard.delegate = self
    }
} // end of View Controller

extension ViewController: RemoveKeyboardDelegate {
    func removeKeyboard() {
        _ = hexField.map { $0.inputView?.removeFromSuperview() }
    }
}
```

An example Xcode 12 project using Swift 5 is provided here:
https://github.com/PepperoniJoe/HexadecimalKeyboard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**First case**, there are keyboard type given as mentioned below we can set the `textField.keyboardType` property and use it.

```
public enum UIKeyboardType : Int {    
    case `default` // Default type for the current input method.    
    case asciiCapable // Displays a keyboard which can enter ASCII characters    
    case numbersAndPunctuation // Numbers and assorted punctuation.    
    case URL // A type optimized for URL entry (shows . / .com prominently).    
    case numberPad // A number pad with locale-appropriate digits (0-9, ۰-۹, ०-९, etc.). Suitable for PIN entry.    
    case phonePad // A phone pad (1-9, *, 0, #, with letters under the numbers).    
    case namePhonePad // A type optimized for entering a person's name or phone number.
    case emailAddress // A type optimized for multiple email address entry (shows space @ . prominently).
    @available(iOS 4.1, *)
    case decimalPad // A number pad with a decimal point.
    @available(iOS 5.0, *)
    case twitter // A type optimized for twitter text entry (easy access to @ #)
    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    case webSearch // A default keyboard type with URL-oriented addition (shows space . prominently).
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    case asciiCapableNumberPad // A number pad (0-9) that will always be ASCII digits.
    public static var alphabet: UIKeyboardType { get } // Deprecated
}
```

The **Second case** is, you want to restrict the user not to enter unwanted values (like you only need 1-9 and a-z) in that case you can use `func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool` delegate and validate the user input and input character is according to your requirement return `true` else return `false`.

And the **Third case** if it is optional to use given keyboard as the user than better create a custom keyboard, see this [Apple developer reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW1Apple). and [nice tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/custom-keyboard-tutorial/) that I have also used to learn.

Comment: Yes I know that but I just want to know that is it possible to extend existing keyboard type ?

Comment: There are also ways to create custom keyboards but it will be really good if you explain your requirement clearly.

Comment: I want keyboard that has only hex character enable on it, user can see clearly that he can only enter hex character, or only hex character is visible on keyboard

Comment: Correct but as a user can I switch it back to normal keyboard? or forcefully I need to use only hex characters?