# Custom Keyboard Accessory view input

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have created a custom accessory view to supplement the standard Apple alpha iOS keyboard.
The purpose is to add a line of numeric keys to prevent flipping back and forth between keyboard views.  At first, I created a toolbar and loaded it with a set  of 0 - 9 titled buttonItems and it functioned quite well. However, it looked terrible, not at all like the alpha keys despite adding a rounded rect background image to each key because the system apparently prevents customizing font size and button spacing inside the stack view of the toolbar.  Therefore, I created a UIView xib and loaded it with a stackView full of customized numerical buttons. When I add the UIView as the accessory view it looks pretty darn close to the rest of the Apple Alpha keyboard.  The issue now is that the touch-up events go to the UIView class of the accessory view.  Is there a clever, efficient way to have the button presses in the accessory emulate the std keyboard feeding into TextField: shouldChangeCharactersIn?  I could package the button presses into a local notification event to get it into the class holding the textField but that seems terribly inelegant!  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Stay Safe!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57275689/1271826

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer, but I did implement notification on key button press with an observer in the main view class. The observer does a TextField.insertText which is suboptimal since I will need to refactor the several hundred lines of code that performs real-time language translation in the shouldChangeCharacters methods. Ah well.