# iOS/Swift: How do remove the spacebar, return key, and number key from the keyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a text field which only requires letters as input and I'm somewhat space-constrained, so I'd like to customize the keyboard like they've done in this crossword puzzle app:

[image: Keyboard on crossword puzzle app]

Notice how the bottom row, which is normally the number key, spacebar, and return key, are missing.  Here's what the keyboard normally looks like:

[image]

If I've got a UITextField, is there a way to customize the keyboard which it uses when it gets focus to not include these keys?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is a public API that lets you do that. They might have made their own keyboard.

Comment: refer:https://github.com/danielsaidi/KeyboardKit and https://medium.com/swift-india/creating-a-custom-keyboard-in-ios-a75e7d5cc5ef#:~:text=First%2C%20select%20your%20Project(In,it%20in%20the%20Plist%20file.

As You have to make your own custom keyboard...!!!

Comment: The NYTimes Crossword app (which is what your screen snapshot would appear to be from) is not the standard keyboard with buttons removed, but likely is their own (or third party) custom [`inputView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621092-inputview) or keyboard. Conceptually this isn't very complicated (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57275689/1271826#57275689), but there are a lot of little details. The NYTimes app does a decent job, reproducing many standard behaviors, it fails on other scores (e.g. doesn't size appropriately for iPhone Max devices).

Comment: E.g., here is [the keyboard NYTimes Crossword app on iPhone Max](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpPM2.jpg). It's very strange it doesn't go all the way across and the fact that they've left space at the bottom. It demonstrates that they didn’t just remove/adjust buttons on a standard keyboard, but rather that they recreated it from scratch (and, arguably, not quite right, either).

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot and the links.  I'll play around with these and see what I can make.