# How to toggle only custom keyboard in textField - Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

So, I made my custom keyboard extension for my app. It works, but the problem is that the only way how can I use it is changing manually from default keyboard. I can't choose to open only it in textFiled's preferences (in keyboard type): [Only these variants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BxdB.png).
Is there any variant how can I open it automatically as textField is pressed?
P.S. I forgot to mention that I am using UIKit (iOS).
P.P.S Well, I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33692231/16016286) that custom view can be created to replace keyboard at all. But what I've asked, is it possible just to replace default keyboards with my own one.

Comment: It'd help if you said what platform and framework you're using; the answer might vary depending on whether you're writing for macOS or iOS, AppKit, UIKit, or SwiftUI.

Comment: I am writing for iOS using UIKit.