# Customising the Decimal pad in my app

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Swift...

So I've got an existing app and I'm working on its appearance. The current task is customising the decimal pad that pops up when the user hits a textField.

I've looked around on how to make it but it always seems that you have to go into the iPhone/ipad settings and add the custom keyboard.

eg. [This StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511973/swift-adding-custom-keyboard-or-numpad-in-app)
and they all seem to point to this same tutorial..
[iOS 8: Creating a Custom Keyboard](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-creating-a-custom-keyboard-in-swift--cms-22344)

My problem is that I don't want the user to have to go into settings.
So the question is....IS THIS POSSIBLE?

The following pic is what I want to use. I have made this in an XIB file through adding a target keyboard which makes the new folder with KeyboardViewController.swift , info.plist and NumPad.xib. Though i think I'm on the wrong track, can someone point me the right way please.

Also anyone know the exact dimensions this view should be.. assuming what I'm asking is in fact possible. Let me know if I'm not being clear enough!
[NumPad.xib(pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Igl7S.png)

Many many thanks,
Steve

SOLUTION: Thanks to Andrea for correcting my search keywords. It led me to [this Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474771/a-swift-example-of-custom-views-for-data-input-custom-in-app-keyboard) which hopefully sends some others to the correct end of the internet that have mistakes custom keyboard with custom input views!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is possible without going into settings, but they are called *custom input views*.
You should look into `inputViews` here what Apple says about them [Custom views for data input](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html).
Basically when the user press a text field instead of loading the usual keyboard it loads an `inputView` that you specify, pay attention that custom keyboard term is misleading. If you google for tutorial you'll find most probably link like the ones that you found.
For a practical example check this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29474/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-custom-input-view-tutorial) or [this](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/03/12/customizing-the-ios-keyboard/), is a little bit old, but the principle are still the same

Comment: Thats great thanks heaps, i thought that might've been the case, searching for the wrong thing!